# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 for groupby in laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I want to group all duplicate rows  but I got error

**Here is below error**

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42000]:
> Syntax error or access violation: 1055
> 'car_web.dependencies.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from `dependencies` where `make_dep` = 3
> group by `model_dep`) in file C:\xampp\htdocs\car-parts-web\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php
> on line 671

**I also change in database.php file**

```
'strict' => true,
'modes' => [
    //'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY', // Disable this to allow grouping by one column
    'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
    'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
    'NO_ZERO_DATE',
    'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
    'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER',
    'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
],
```

but give same error

**here is below my query**

```
$data = DB::table('dependencies')
        ->where('make_dep', '=', $make)
        ->groupBy('model_dep')
        ->get();
```

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments tp set functions.

Comment: After changed, have you clear the caches? `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: no cache not cleared let me cleared

Comment: try in `database.php` inside mysql array `'strict' => false,` make it false and try

Answer (score 2):

You are confused in `GROUP BY` statement because in `GROUP BY` we need to use any aggregate function like `SUM`, `COUNT`, ... .

If you want to remove duplicate rows you can simply use `DISTINCT` method, if you want to group data you need any aggregate function.